# Java Awt mouse position coordinates calculation

Tags: java, awt, mouse, mouse-cursor

I can get the Position of the cursor by the following code, but I don`t understand how the coordinates are calculated.

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

If the mouse is in the right top corner the coordinates are "java.awt.Point[x=2047,y=0]", but the resolution of my screen is 2560 x 1440 so I expected the coordinates to be [x=2560,y=0].

So how are these coordinated calculated?

Answer (score 0):

When I try something like:

```
while(true){
    System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Its printing out:

```
java.awt.Point[x=1919,y=0]
```

And I got 1920 1080

So its seems to be some problem with your screen/system. Are you sure your system "knows" that you have such a screen?

Answer (score 0):

My windows options for "Display -> Scale and layout" are set to 125%.
Thats the problem, if i set it to 100% it works like expected.